# Integration features enabled but drives not available

Tags: windows-xp-mode, microsoft-virtual-pc

Frustratingly, after a recent update to Windows XP mode integration features, the availability of shared disks from the hosts has been impaired.

Does anyone know any kind of workaround or fix (excluding dropbox et al)?

I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling as per http://www.sevenforums.com/virtualization/63710-refreshing-xp-mode.html#post568715

At one point restarting the machine appeared to have worked, but today again I am without access to my host.

Interestingly audio and copy and paste to and from the machine are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue after installing the Remote Desktop Protocol 8.0 update ([KB2592687](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/2592687)). I don’t know exactly what causes the problem, but since I don’t need RDP 8.0 I simply uninstalled the update to restore redirected drives in XP Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today: in integration features, my drives were correctly selected but not display in explorer.

I figured out this issue by logging off XP mode user and login again.
My drives were display correctly this time.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a network connection on the host machine and connected correctly to the virtual machine in order for the shared disks to be shown

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another solution (thank You [@Brian Nixon](https://superuser.com/users/213104/brian-nixon) for inspiration).
Same thing happened to me after [KB2830477](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830477) update.
It is also related to Remote Desktop and "lets you use the new Remote Desktop Services features" ;-)

Best regards, Lucas